# Nightmare JS doesn't return NodeList

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I use Nightmare JS in my Node Js project; This is my code

```
  async function someFunc() { 
    let nightmare; 
    try {   nightmare = Nightmare({show: true, typeInterval: 10, waitTimeout: 5000});
                    await nightmare
                        .goto(`https://example.com`)
                        .click(".button")
                        .wait(".someClass")

                    let result = await nightmare.evaluate(function () {

                        return document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
                    });

                    console.log(result);

    } catch (error) { 
    throw error; 
    } finally { 
    await nightmare.end(); 
    } 
}
```

"SomeClass" contains several elements(e.g. 3). I want to get in result Node List, but i get only empty object; This code works only if i return in this way:

```
 return document.querySelectorAll(".someClass")[0].textContent;
```

Why  cant i  return full NodeList in result ?

Comment: is that a top-level `await`? what is the surrounding code?

Comment: pls update the original post

Comment: updated the original post